# Como alterar o atributo de um objeto recebido por parâmetro em um método?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Estou tentando implementar um exemplo bem simplório de utilização de classes na linguagem C++. Bem, resumindo, existem dois objetos (cliente1 e cliente2), que representam duas contas bancárias. Dentro da classe **Conta**, há um método **transferir()**, responsável, claro, por realizar a transferência entre essas duas contas.

Bem, o problema é que eu não consigo atualizar o valor do saldo da conta que recebe a transferência.

No exemplo do código, a conta 'Pedro Gonçalves' deveria possuir o saldo final de 1000, no entanto, o saldo permanece inalterado (450), mesmo após a transferência. O objeto é passado como parâmetro no método **transferir**.

Eu tentei alterar o atributo **saldo** desta conta através do setter que eu defini, mas não funciona.

Alguém pode indicar os meus erros?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Conta{
    private:
        string nome, cpf, rg;
        float saldo;
    public:
        void setDados(string a, string b, string c, float s){
            nome = a;
            cpf = b;
            rg = c;
            saldo = s;
        }
        void setSaldo(float s){
            saldo = s;
        }
        string getNome(){
            return nome;
        }
        string getCpf(){
            return cpf;
        }
        string getRg(){
            return rg;
        }
        float getSaldo(){
            return saldo;
        }

        void transferir(Conta dest, float valor){
            if(saldo >= valor){
                //O saldo da conta atual possui valor de transferência subtraído. 
                saldo -= valor;

                float saldo_destino = dest.getSaldo();
                //O saldo da conta destino é incrementado com o valor da transferência.
                saldo_destino += valor;
            
                dest.setSaldo(saldo_destino);

                cout << "Transferência realizada com sucesso." << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "Saldo insuficiente para realizar a operação" << endl;
        }
};

int main(void){
    Conta cliente1, cliente2;

    cliente1.setDados("Pedro Gonçalves", "123456", "1", 450.00);
    cliente2.setDados("João Santos", "654321", "2", 1550.00);


    cliente2.transferir(cliente1, 550);

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << cliente1.getNome() << " possui saldo de R$" << cliente1.getSaldo() << endl;
    cout << cliente2.getNome() << " possui saldo de R$" << cliente2.getSaldo() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Tem diversos problemas nesse código, mesmo resolvendo essa questão ainda terá um código ruim em mãos.

Comment: Ajudou bastante. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer é passar o objeto para o método **por referência**, isto é passando o endereço na memória para o objeto, em vez de passá-lo **por valor** como está escrito no seu código, onde o método copia o valor do objeto em outro objeto e as alterações nos dados no novo objeto criado pelo método não surtirão efeito no objeto que foi passado na chamada da função.

Para resolver isso você pode utilizar apontadores.

Seu método reescrito ficaria assim:

```
        void transferir(Conta* dest, float valor){
            if(saldo >= valor){
                //O saldo da conta atual possui valor de transferência subtraído. 
                saldo -= valor;

                float saldo_destino = dest->getSaldo();
                //O saldo da conta destino é incrementado com o valor da transferência.
                saldo_destino += valor;
            
                dest->setSaldo(saldo_destino);

                cout << "Transferência realizada com sucesso." << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "Saldo insuficiente para realizar a operação" << endl;
        }
```

E na chamada para a função, tendo em vista que o objeto cliente1 não é um apontador, você passaria o endereço na memória dele, dessa forma:

```
cliente2.transferir(&cliente1, 550);
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava, Raphael! Eu, na verdade, tinha feito isso com a utilização de ponteiros, mas recebi alguns problemas no momento da compilação. Foram resolvidos. Grato!